# Why doesnt Regex.Match have a GetEnumerator function?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-3.5, standards

Regex.Match has a .Success and .NextMatch why doesnt it have a GetEnumerator function?

With my logic it seems easy enough to implement. But it isnt in 3.5 so can anyone tell me why not?

```
foreach (var m in Regex.Match("dummy text", "mm")) error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' because 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you want `Regex.Matches`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex.Match
```

returns the first instance of the pattern that is matched in the string.

You probably want

```
Regex.Matches
```

, which returns a MatchCollection of all the matches in the string.

[MSDN Article on Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Because the `Match` object is immutable (and `NextMatch()` does not change the context of the current match, but gives you a reference to the next one, which is different from `IEnumerable.MoveNext()` ).

But you can do this:

```
for (Match m=Regex.Match("dummy text", "mm"); m.Success; m=m.NextMatch()) {
    // loop code
}
```

Comment: Ahh its immutable +1. And +1 for everyone else bc they mentioned matches.